# "Add Account" in OneDrive Prompts for email address of old company

Tags: onedrive

This probably shouldn't bother me as much as it does, but I did some work for a company about a year ago, including being connected to OneDrive and various other things. I disconnected all of it, and I thought all references were gone, but if I do "Add an Account" in OneDrive, it is defaulting to that company's address. I'd like OneDrive (and everything) to forget about that.

I've checked credential manager and I can't see anything with a reference to that company, or their email. I've checked through the registry, I've reset OneDrive. Does anyone have any other ideas where it might be so that I can remove it?

Comment: Perhaps you can get an answer at https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, if you do *not* get one here.

Comment: Have you tried just switching your account? Make sure the account isn't linked to your user profile (Settings).

Comment: Please check whether the thread is helpful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/delete-remove-locked-onedrive-account/f5c87bd6-aca5-4184-9553-6c96900923f2#:~:text=1%201.%20Open%20the%20Registry%20Editor%20by%20clicking,4.%20Delete%20the%20highlighted%20folder%3E%20OK.%20More%20items. Besides, please make sure you do not connect the OneDrive account service in Office apps.